# Javascript Image Recognition Game

Tags: javascript, image-recognition

So I'm working on a school project.
The user is presented an image recognition game with one main image (geometric shape) and under a line of other images (geometric shapes). The purpose of the game is to choose the same shape as the main image amongst the underlying list of shapes. I used a previous quiz-script I had from before for a simple javascript-quiz and just replaced the answers and questions with images.

The task also asks that I count the number of incorrect answers and do not continue to the next question until the current page has registered a correct answer. This is something I am struggling with, and I have commented on this in the code itself.

```
var allQuestions = [{
    question: 'https://image.ibb.co/gXSwen/kvadrat.png',
    choices: ['https://image.ibb.co/g4zben/sirkel.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/gXSwen/kvadrat.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/mCrpzn/rtrekant.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/mVHJs7/lstrekant.png'],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },
  {
    question: 'https://image.ibb.co/g4zben/sirkel.png',
    choices: ['https://image.ibb.co/g4zben/sirkel.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/gXSwen/kvadrat.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/mCrpzn/rtrekant.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/mVHJs7/lstrekant.png'],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },
  {
    question: 'https://image.ibb.co/mVHJs7/lstrekant.png',
    choices: ['https://image.ibb.co/g4zben/sirkel.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/gXSwen/kvadrat.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/mCrpzn/rtrekant.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/mVHJs7/lstrekant.png'],
    correctAnswer: 3
  },
  {
    question: 'https://image.ibb.co/mCrpzn/rtrekant.png',
    choices: ['https://image.ibb.co/g4zben/sirkel.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/gXSwen/kvadrat.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/mCrpzn/rtrekant.png', 'https://image.ibb.co/mVHJs7/lstrekant.png'],
    correctAnswer: 2
  }
];

var correct = 0;
var incorrect = 0;
var selected = [];
var position = 0;
var next = document.getElementById("next");
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var answers = document.getElementById("answers");
var question = document.getElementById("question");
var startcontainer = document.getElementById("startcontainer");
var scorecontainer = document.getElementById("scorecontainer");
var quizcontainer = document.getElementById("quizcontainer");


window.onload = (function() {

  // Display startpage
  quizcontainer.style.display = 'none';
  scorecontainer.style.display = 'none';

  // Display the first question on the click of the start-button
  start.onclick = (function() {
    position = 0;
    correct = 0;
    incorrect = 0;
    selected = [];
    startcontainer.style.display = 'none';
    scorecontainer.style.display = 'none';
    quizcontainer.style.display = 'inline';
    showQuestion();

  });

  //Check the answer: if an answer is selected, execute functions checkAnswer. If an answer is not chosen, alert the user that they need to select an answer. Note that the function checkAnswer is supposed to decide whether or not to display the next question, which depends on the correctness of the answer.
  next.onclick = (function() {
    if ($("#answers input").is(":checked")) {
      checkAnswer();

    } else {
      alert("You need to select an answer.");
    }

  });


  // Creates HTML for the current question
  function showQuestion() {
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = null;
    document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML = null;

    //Loops through the questions from the allQuestions-array and displays them seperately
    if (position < allQuestions.length) {
      question.src = allQuestions[position].question;
      for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[position].choices.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML += "<div><label><input type='radio' name='radio' value='" + allQuestions[position].choices[i] + "'><img src=" + allQuestions[position].choices[i] + "><label></div><br>"
      }
    }
    //When the for-loop has went through the questions, show the amount of right answers.
    else {
      document.getElementById("quizcontainer").style.display = 'none';
      $("#scorecontainer").append("<h1>You got " + correct + " questions correct!</h1>").fadeIn("slow");
    }
  }

  // Function that checks if the answer is correct. Increase the correct-value and continue to the next question if the answer is correct 
  function checkAnswer() {
    selected.push($("#answers input:checked").val());
    var correctAnswer = allQuestions[position].choices[allQuestions[position].correctAnswer];
    if (selected[position] === correctAnswer) {
      correct++;
      position++;
      showQuestion();
    }
    //Counts the number of incorrect answers. I want it to count each wrong answer and not continue (hence why I didn't include position++ here) to the next question until the right answer is chosen. 
    else if (selected[position] !== correctAnswer) {
      incorrect++

    }
  }

});
```

[jsfiddle here (with the html)](https://jsfiddle.net/tjrfL9md/6/)

---

Problem here is function checkAnswer. I have also made an elaborate comment in the code about the issue. So in short the function's task is to check if the answer is correct or incorrect. If it is correct, it increments the correct- and position(current question)-value by 1. Lastly it executes the showQuestion function which displays the next question (There might be a problem with this function but I'm not sure). If the answer is incorrect it increments the incorrect-value by 1.
So if you try the game and select only the correct alternatives it will work as intended and you are told the number of correct answers are 4 out of 4. But if you in any question along the way select the incorrect answer it won't go through. And if you after choosing the wrong answer then select the correct answer, it won't go through even then. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple oversight, the kind I make all the time. You need to modify your checkAnswer function to the following:

```
function checkAnswer() {
    selected.push($("#answers input:checked").val());
    var correctAnswer = allQuestions[position].choices[allQuestions[position].correctAnswer];
    if (selected[position] === correctAnswer) {
      correct++;
      position++;
      showQuestion();
    }
    //Counts the number of incorrect answers. I want it to count each wrong answer and not continue (hence why I didn't include position++ here) to the next question until the right answer is chosen. 
    else if (selected[position] !== correctAnswer) {
      incorrect++
      selected.pop();
    }
}
```

You have to remove the incorrect answer from your array of answers, or else you will never be able to tell that the changed answer is correct. FYI, I am not sure why you need a variable named incorrect at all unless there is some functionality that you plan to add in the future

Comment: Damn thanks bro. And yea, I intend to present the amount of wrong answers to the user through the incorrect-variable. Thanks a lot :)